# discussion φαιλόνην

Tags: greek, new-testament, 2-timothy

discussion φαιλόνην

It has been suggested that the greek word φαιλόνην,as St Paul uses it in 2 Timothy 4:13 has a link to the shroud of Turin, as a early relic of Christianity; with links to the mendalion of the 4th century in Eddessa.

τὸν φαιλόνην ὃν ἀπέλιπον ἐν Τρῳάδι παρὰ Κάρπῳ ἐρχόμενος φέρε, καὶ τὰ βιβλία μάλιστα τὰς μεμβράνας. (2 Tim. 4:13, NA27)

Penulam, quam reliqui Troade apud Carpum, veniens affer tecum, et libros, maxime autem membranas. (Ed. electronica, 2 Tim. 4:13, Biblia Sacra juxta Vulgatam Clementinam)

When you come, bring the cloak I left with Carpus in Troas, the papyrus rolls, and especially the parchments. (2 Tim. 4:13, The New American Bible)

Is there any mileage in this suggestion.

Ray Pyle

Comment: You have not quoted the actual occurrence of the word - just the chapter. And you have not given any evidence of the 'link' to the artefacts you mention. I would suggest that this question is not actually about the text of scripture, hermeneutically, but is a question about religious trophies.

Comment: I agree with Nigel - all the items listed in 2 Tim 4:13 are Paul's personal property, including the cloak.  I cannot see any link here.

Comment: the word means cloak, not shroud which is "linen cloth" σινδόνι in Greek. φαιλονου, ὁ, Latin paenula, a traveling cloak, used for protection against stormy weather (Thayer). Close opinion based.

Answer (score 1):

In 2 Tim 4:13 Paul makes a simple request for Timothy to bring some personal items including his thick cloak for the winter, scrolls, and parchments.  All personal items.  I can see no link, even a tenuous stretched link to the shroud of Turin or any other such object.  Ellicott notes:

> **The cloke that I left at Troas**.--The apparently trivial nature of this request in an Epistle containing such weighty matter, and also
>   the fact of such a wish on the part of one expecting death being made
>   at all, is at first a little puzzling. To explain this seemingly
>   strange request, some have wished to understand by "the cloke" some
>   garment St. Paul was in the habit of wearing when performing certain
>   sacred functions: in other words, as a vestment; but such a
>   supposition would be in the highest degree precarious, for nowhere in
>   the New Testament is the slightest hint given us that any such
>   vestment was ever used in the primitive Christian Church. It is much
>   better to understand the words as simply requesting Timothy, on his
>   way, to bring with him a thick cloak, or mantle, which St. Paul had
>   left with a certain Carpus at Troas. Probably, when he left it, it was
>   summer, and he was disinclined to burden himself in his hurried
>   journey with any superfluous things. Winter was now coming on, and the
>   poor aged prisoner in the cold damp prison, with few friends and scant
>   resources, remembered and wished for his cloak. It is just such a
>   request which the master would make of his disciple, who, knowing well
>   the old man's frail, shattered health, would never be surprised at
>   such a request even in an Epistle so solemn.

Comment: Besides, commentators of prior times (and our own!) forget that such trivialities are there because of, not despite, Paul having used the letter format for his teaching. "This is really me writing. See what big letters I'm using!" and "Oh wait, I also baptized Stephen's household. Can't remember if I baptized anyone else." Sometimes things just pop into your head. :)

Comment: Quite right Luke, I agree

Answer (score 1):

Nadie comenta la posibilidad que oí de un rabino judío-mesiánico en Israel. Pablo pedía su manto de oración, su "talit", y obviamente sus rollos personales. Todo judío, y más los maestros como él, llevaban consigo sus libros de la Torah. Hierra quien piensa que Pablo dejó alguna vez de ser un verdadero judío, ceremonialmente hablando. (Hch. 21:26, Hch. 24:17-18....). Debemos ponernos lentes adecuados para leer la Palabra de Dios. Reconocer el entorno en el que se desarrollaron estas palabras, y todas. Ponemos vallas, propias o adquiridas, a la riqueza de las Escrituras.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! As the site is in English, it should go without saying that answers should also be in English. Also, when you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help)'s sections on both asking and answering questions.